# Create nested dict from nested list

Tags: python

How can I transform list of nested lists to nested dictonary using python?

```
students = [[1, 'John', 'Smith'], [2, 'Anna', 'Jones']]
```

to

```
students_dict = {'1': {'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Smith'},
             '2': {'name': 'Anna', 'surname': 'Jones'}}
```

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if your problem is solved.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use unpacking:

```
students = [[1, 'John', 'Smith'], [2, 'Anna', 'Jones']]
result = {a:dict(zip(['name', 'surname'], b)) for a, *b in students}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Smith'}, 2: {'name': 'Anna', 'surname': 'Jones'}}
```

Comment: Any thing similar for 2.7?

Comment: @PySaad List slicing will suffice: `{i[0]:dict(zip(['name', 'surname'], i[1:])) for i in students}`

Answer (score 0):

Your keys of the sub-dictionaries are:

```
keys = ["name", "surname"]
```

Make the sub-dictionaries by zipping the keys and the values (after the first element) together, and add the first element as key to the outer dictionary:

```
students_dict = {d[0] : dict(zip(keys, d[1:])) for d in students}
```